# symfony/http-foundation doesn't implement psr/http-message

Tags: php, symfony, php-psr

why symfony http-foundation doesn't implement psr http-message ??
I want to use php frameworks interoperability.

in my opinion router , dispatcher , ioc container, http message and ...
should have a psr interfaces and all frameworks should obey the interfaces.

so I want to simply implement my project not to use a specific php framework
just use php packages which I need.

should I implement all that stuff myself ??
isn't it obvious that all frameworks should implement psr interfaces??

and after all why other psr standards (router, dispatcher, container)are taking too much time??

Comment: PSR interfaces are relatively new and Symfony can't break all existing applications. Http-message is supported via bridge http://symfony.com/blog/psr-7-support-in-symfony-is-here (http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/psr7.html)

Comment: I've already seen that package and I think it's not standard to get multiple package for just http message.
and it's more than 3 month as I remember that psr packages are ready to work.
php would be at least 5 times stronger if all frameworks and packages obey the psr interfaces.
symfony is just a framework nothing more.
I think symfony framework Delusion of being number one in php community.

Comment: @mhndev 3 months is not a very long time for a big framework to rewrite one of the major components and make the community implement it. (especially the second thing takes much much much more time). Btw, I don't think Symfony has the illusion of being the number one, there is no popular framework that implemented PSR-7 yet...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

HttpFoundation and PSR-7 have a very very different basis (the biggest difference is the fact that PSR-7 objects are immutable, while HttpFoundation's objects are mutable). This makes it hard (if not impossible) for Symfony to update HttpFoundation to the PSR-7 interface without introducing a complete rewrite (and thus lots of backwards compatibility breaks for all current Symfony applications).

In order to still provide a way of supporting PSR-7, you can use the [`symfony/psr-http-message-bridge`](https://github.com/symfony/psr-http-message-bridge) ([docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/psr7.html)), which provides factories to transform the HttpFoundation `Request` and `Response` into PSR-7 request and responses messages (and the other way around).

This is done automatically for you when you typehint against the PSR-7 interfaces in your controller instead of the HttpFoundation request.

Comment: I hope I see httpfoundation implement psr messages soon.
thanks.